# Let T be a consistent, axiomatizable theory extending Q.

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

Question: Let $T$ be a consistent, axiomatizable theory extending $Q$. Let $P+$ be the set of (code numbers for) sentences provable from $T$; let $P−$ be the set of (code numbers for) sentences disprovable from $T$ . Show that there is no recursive set $R$ such that both $P+ \subseteq R$ and $R\cap P− = \emptyset$.

I know that the Diagonal Lemma can be used. There is a proof that I was thinking about following the format for. So my attempt was going to be to suppose otherwise. Is this a good approach, or what am I missing here? I feel skeptical about just following a proof for the diagonal lemma.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough outline.

As you suggest, assume the opposite and try deduce a contradiction. So assuming there is such a recursive $R$, it can be represented in $\mathcal{Q}$ by a  formula $\phi$. That is, $x\in R \leftrightarrow Q\vdash \phi (x). $

Diagonalize $\phi$. If $G$ is the sentence that diagonalizes $\phi$ then there are two cases. Either $\mathbb N \models G $ or $\mathbb N \models \neg  G$. In either case, use facts about when sentences true in standard arithmetic can be proved by $\mathcal Q$ to deduce contradictions.